# Java implementation to handle callback messages

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

I have the following situation I need to handle in my code:

```
public class Class1 {

    IRequester requester;

    public Class1(Requester impl) {
        requester = impl;
    }

    public List doSomething() {
        requester.request1();  // sends messages to a set of nodes
        //do some more local processing
        list = requester.request2(); // sends some more messages and returns a list
        return list;
    }
}
```

In this case request1() sends a request to a set of nodes and returns a result which will be used locally for more processing, and then the request2() is made which returns a list. This needs to be returned at the end of execution of doSomething(). request1() and request2() are done through requester which is of type IRequester

```
public interface IRequester {

    request1();

    List request2();
}
```

Now request1() and request2() are implemented by the class which actually does the requests. This is the class that handles the communication between the nodes.

```
public NetworkManager implements IRequester {

    request1() {

        // Create an operation
        // Add callback to the operation             
        // schedule operation
    }

    request2() {

    }
}
```

Now, my issue is that when I implement request1() here in there I need to create  a procedure which will send a message to the node. This procedure can have a callback attached. When the node responds it returns the result. How do I implement this such that it returns the result at the end of my request1?

Comment: you can not, because you dont know how long it will take to the node  to get the info ready for you, you need a callback between them

Answer (score 0):

One of ways would be to use `CompletableFuture` to track asynchronous value.

```
public NetworkManager implements IRequester {

    Client client; //some client that works with callbacks

    CompletableFuture<String> request1() {
        CompletableFuture<String> result = new CompletableFuture<>();
        client.request1(someArguments, (calbackResult) -> result.complete(calbackResult));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here `result` is a promise that as soon as callback is executed it will provide a value. Until that it is going to be empty.

So `NetworkManager` returns `CompletableFuture` which means that result is not ready yet or will be never ready (if callback never happens).

When `Class1.doSomething` tries to get result from `CompletableFuture` current thread is going to block until value is available or occurs a timeout.

This approach also makes code in `Class1.doSomething` more stable, because it is now forced to handle issues with timeouts and missing result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to wait on callback using Observer as the callback and Thread.sleep to simulate long running async task:

```
public Object request(){
    CompletableFuture<Object> cf = new CompletableFuture<Object>();
    runAsync( (o, arg) -> cf.complete(arg) );
    try { return cf.get(); } 
    catch (Exception e) {throw new RuntimeException(e); }
}

public void runAsync(final Observer o){
    new Thread( () -> {
        try { Thread.sleep(3000L); }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        String result = "abc";
        o.update(null, result);
    } ).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the return type of request1() is void so you cannot return value from it .
But in the implementation class of IRequester , you can pass a resultObject ,
whenever the request1() method is execute it will store the result in the result Object, and when you need to get the result , you can get it from the ResultObject

```
class ResultObject{
getResult(); ///return result
setResult(); ///store result
}


public NetworkManager implements IRequester {

private ResultObject callBackResult;

public ResultObject getResult(){
return callBackResult;
}
public void setResult(ResultObject value){
this.callBackResult=value;
}

request1() {

    // Create an operation
    this.setResult(callProcedure());
    // schedule operation
}

request2() {

}
```

}

```
public class Main{  


public static void main(String args){
IRequester r=new NetworkManger();
ResultObject res=new ResultObject();
r.setResult(res);
r.request1();
r.getResult();
r.request2();
}
 }
```