# Hold the flow of the Java program

Tags: java, swing

I have a GUI developed in Swing. The constructor of the GUI is called from another Java class which contains the main function for the Java package.

The use case is after the GUI opens the flow of the Java class file should be stopped until the frame closes by clicking the 'Finish' button, because the output of the UI is a list of Strings which is used by the functions later.

I tried using invokeAndWait and Swing sleep and both didnt work out. Any suggestions (not the code) for implementing the use case.

Comment: Use a modal JDialog such as a JOptionPane for this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels could you please elaborate it a little?

Comment: @vikky2405 Well, you could just do a quick goggle for [java modal dialog](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=java+modal+dialog&oq=java+modal+dialo&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.2597j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and see what you find, or you could search SO for a simular query which will probably lead you to [How to make dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

In case `JDialog` or `JOPtionPane` are not what you want to use. You can:

1) Create an `Observer`.

2) Create your GUI from main thread, pass `Observer` to it and start it on EDT using `invokeLater`.

3) Use CompletableFuture to wait untill your GUI will call back on `Observer.update(list of strings)` when your "Finish" button is clicked.

4) Get your list of strings from `Observer`.

See this link on how it is done [Java implementation to handle callback messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267717/java-implementation-to-handle-callback-messages/44273243#44273243).